# Looking for the longest "non-variant" word

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking for the longest English word that has no variants, where a variant might be

1. A singular or plural form
2. A conjugated form
3. A form in another part of speech

For example, `mouse` would fail by all those rules: it has a plural ("mice"); as a verb, it has conjugated forms ("mousing", "moused"); it has an adverbial form ("mousy") and other noun forms ("mouser").

Obviously, pretty much any verb would be out, as would any countable noun that has a plural.  I'm also excluding words that are just conglomerations of other words like "whatsoever".

Right now, I've got some five-letter word -- "moose", "there" -- and "through", which has seven but I'm thinking  should be excluded because of "throughway" and "throughput".

Comment: `throughway` and `throughput` aren't variants of `through`.  I might argue that `mooses` is valid when referring to types of moose, however :P

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves trivia (in the non-academic sense). Better on Puzzling.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the invariable words are the **function words**: interjections, adverbs, etc.

I excluded:

1. Words like "underground", which I thought you could disagree with as *under* + *ground*;
2. Words like "intentionally", because it had variants like "intentional" or "unintentional";
3. Words like "old-fashioned" because of both the reasons above.

So, selecting among them, I could find:

- **[Draconian](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/draconian)** = 9 letters;
- **[Tomorrow](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/tomorrow)** = 8 letters.

Comment: *Underneath* is a combination of *under* + *neath*, so I am not sure how it is different from *underground*.  *Draconian* is an adjective that comes from the noun *Draco*.  *Tomorrow* is *to* + *morrow* (also it can be pluralized as *tomorrows*).

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Even **Schadenfreude** is a combination of Schaden (harm) + Freude (joy). About Draconian and tomorrow... If we consider even the etymological combinations through history, than we can exclude basically every word.

Comment: I removed **Underneath**. By the way, technically **neath** does not exist. It's an abbreviation of **beneath**, it's even displayed as **'neath** in my NOAD. It doesn't cancel what you said about it being a combination of two words, I know, I just wanted to be precise.

Comment: @Alenanno: The word *Schadenfreude* is only a combination of those words in German.  In English, *Schadenfreude* is a whole-word borrowing whose components are nontransparent.  *Schaden* and *freude* are not words in English at all.  The words *Draconian* and *tomorrow* are made up of English morphemes (and a name).  If *Draconian* is worth including, then why not *machiavellian*?

Comment: How about Shakespearean? Thanks for the hint, @Matthew.

Comment: @Malvolio, @Kosmonaut: what about words like "**trousers**"? Although it has a derivative "trousered", apparently... :/

Comment: @Kosmonaut -- I've heard it said that are more than a million words in the English language.  There are certainly more than a million additional names in the world, people and places?  You want to include those as "words"? What about all names in human history?  What about nonce words and scientific formulae and onomatopoeia?  What about numbers written out as words?  There's a literally infinite supply of those. You have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: @Malvolio: If you want to draw a line, you can much more practically and realistically use frequency as a metric.  If a word is not used with a certain level of frequency, it is not an "active" member of the lexicon.  Some archaic common nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc. will not make the cut, but any reasonably recognizable names will. Otherwise, you're stuck trying to define arbitrary criteria that determine whether e.g. "Zipper", "Google" and "American" should be words. Frequency-as-wordhood also reflects the fact that words can gradually fall out of use rather than staying fixed over time.

Answer (score 1):

> **OBDIPLOSTEMONOUS** = 16 letters
>
> **RHADAMANTHINE** = 13 letters
>
> **ZENZIZENZIZENZIC** = 16 letters

Definition of obdiplostemonous: Having twice the number of stamens as the number of petals.
Definition of rhadamanthine : Rigorously just and severe.

Definition of zenzizenzizenzic: The eight power of a number

Comment: As a verb, *statuminate* has conjugational forms.

Comment: Sadly, `"etiquettes"` yields more than 4 *million* hits on Google.   Plus, it just occurred to me: `statuette` is just a diminutive of `statue`. The search continues.

Comment: *pneu* = lungs, *mono* = one, *ultra* = beyond, *microscopic* = microscopic, *silico* = silicon-related, *volcano* = volcano, *coniosis* = disease caused by dust.  All of these words are used to productively derive new English words, or are words themselves.  Also, it is [an artificial word, only used when people are naming long words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis).

Answer (score 1):

[*Schadenfreude*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/schadenfreude) — Though this word has variants in German, it lacks them in English.

Answer (score 1):

If medical terms count, how about the 45-letter standard English word

> pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

which of course means "black lung disease"?

I know of no variants. I don't see a rule against combination words, just forms of the same word. Does anyone else know of a variant to this one?

(Too bad variants are excluded.  My favorite longest one-syllable word is "strengths."  Nine letters.  Yes, it has variants, but one syllable, you know...?)

Answer (score 0):

try [supercalifragilisticexpialidocious](http://www.wordnik.com/words/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) (it's 34 letters!)

> ```
>   –adjective
> ```
>
> 1. Fantastic, very wonderful

or [try this protein molecule with 189,819 letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titin) - you can find the whole word [here](http://othyr.com/titin.html) - I think the plural of this word is the same word.

Comment: *Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious-ly*.